# Can applicationWillResignActive be used for pausing the application

Tags: iphone

In the MainViewController, I have a play/pause button. I was having problem in coding for the pause function because when i was using audio player pause it was pausing only the audio player but in background my application was still executing. I have used `NSTimer` for displaying various `UIViewControllers`. While audio player is paused it is still displaying `UIViewControllers` because of `NSTimer`.Whereas i wanted complete pause audio player & application execution as well at the same time.

I found this `-applicationwillresignactive`. Do you think this `-applicationwillresignactive` can help me when i want complete pause audio player plus application pause.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidEnterBackground are called when home button is pressed.

Comment: what is the other way to pause the app for that purpose